# React material-ui: centering items on Toolbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement a toolbar on a page in which I have three `ToolbarGroup` components:

```
            <Toolbar>
                <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true} float="left">
                    {prevButton}
                </ToolbarGroup>

                <ToolbarGroup>
                    {releaseBtn}
                </ToolbarGroup>

                <ToolbarGroup lastChild={true} float="right">
                    {nextButton}
                </ToolbarGroup>
            </Toolbar>
```

The general idea is that `prevButton` should render all the way to the left of the toolbar (it does), `nextButton` should render all the way to the right (it does)... and that `releaseBtn` should be centered on the toolbar (not currently happening).

Per the [material-ui docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toolbar) there doesn't appear to be some easy setting for `centered={true}`-- how can I accomplish this?

I've tried manually setting the style on the middle `ToolbarGroup` to `margin: 0px auto` but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You should just be able to add a { margin: auto, width: (whatever it needs to be) } for the middle one as a style prop to center it

Comment: AHA - I did need to set a width, but I also had to set `float: none` in an inline style. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final solution for me was to do this:

```
            <Toolbar>
                <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true} float="left">
                    {prevButton}
                </ToolbarGroup>

                <ToolbarGroup style={{ 
                    float       : 'none', 
                    width       : '200px',
                    marginLeft  : 'auto',
                    marginRight : 'auto'
                }}>
                    {releaseBtn}
                </ToolbarGroup>

                <ToolbarGroup lastChild={true} float="right">
                    {nextButton}
                </ToolbarGroup>
            </Toolbar>
```

I first had to set the middle `ToolbarGroup` with no float (not an option through the material-ui props) and then play with the width/margins. I imagine your mileage may vary depending on what you shove inside the `ToolbarGroup`.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone runs into this in 2021 or later like I did, material-ui's `Toolbar` uses Flexbox under the hood, so all you have to do is apply a custom class (or override the default one in the theme):

```css
.myToolbar {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

`space-between` will distribute the children alongside the main horizontal axis:
[image]
(picture from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

In new versions of Material UI you can just use the `sx` prop:

https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content

```js
<Toolbar sx={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}> // or "center" for a single element
...
</Toolbar>
```