# How centering items on Toolbar in version "@mui/material": "^5.11.3"

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have this example getted from thier site
https://codesandbox.io/s/0f50jf?file=/demo.js

I am trying to center all toolbar elements in the center  using:

```
sx= {{
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center'}}
```

But nothing is working

How can i make

```
justifyContent
```

Working with toolbar ?
I saw this solution [React material-ui: centering items on Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732158/react-material-ui-centering-items-on-toolbar)
but it is not not working

Comment: Do you want all the element to be in the center or only the search bar?

Comment: Only the search bar

Answer (score 1):

In flex box, there is a trick which helps to center element in flex box, margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto, I have applied this CSS to search bar, which make the search to be in center.

Created A CodeSandbox [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-bash-swmij5?file=/demo.js)

Relevant Resource

CSS trick article on Flex box and Margin Auto: [Link](https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/)

Medium Article on Flex box and margin: [Link](https://medium.com/hackernoon/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6)

Let me know if you have query, happy to help

Comment: thank, but justifyContent center not working ?

Comment: To center search bar, I would recommend to use justifyContent: space-between. 
Css Tricks Article on Flex box will help you understand more on this. Flex box is complex topic. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If his answer help you solve the problem, can you mark this as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried justifiyContent: 'center'

Comment: Yes but it is not working even i see the css result in the dom

Comment: It would be better if you can share full code. It is difficult to tell where the issue is from this code